# Loading Data into SAP BW via SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2008, sap-bw

I am trying to get the Microsoft Connector for SAP BW ver 1.1 working in our environment.

This is to push data into BW only not extract it.

I have put the LibRFC.dll in place on the SQL server and can create a connection to BW. When I test the connection in SSIS it says OK so I know this bit is fine.
When I do a test load I get an RFC failure.

I have setup my Info cube and any necessary objects in BW.

I have even looked on the gateway and can see the attempts but I need to interrogate the error at a lower level to find out what is going on.

I am using SQL 2008 R2 with the Sap BW connecter version 1.1.

Can anybody offer me any help with this issue as its becoming quite critical.

Comment: How do you do a "test load"? Run the package in SSDT? Or run it some other way? What is the exact error message that SSIS provides?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299430(v=sql.100).aspx ... You might have read this ?

Comment: I have only extracted data from SAP BW but when I ran into RFC errors, I generally had to take it back to the SAP folks and have them look into it. General purpose though, make sure your data types align as best you can. That means nvarchar/unicode for strings and it's been too long since I looked at it for numeric values

Comment: What version of BW are you running?

Comment: Hi Bryan - we are running 7.3

Comment: We were also struggling to find where to find the  saprfc.ini on the server (UNIX) because the RFC Program will not stay afloat as its set to 'Registered Server Program' on the RFC Destination. On a doc we read it said we had to make a change to the ini file to allow it to stay up. At the moment we have a command line running which keeps the connection up. If I do a 'test on' the connection in Source System (in SAP GUI (Transaction RSA1) it works fine. Again if I do a connection from SSIS the connection succeeds, but I cannot see any mappings.

Comment: Nick - I do a test load by just clicking on the "Test Load" button on the SAP Destination component inside the SSIS Gui, but this will fail because no destination mappings I can map to are showing in the mappings tab.

Comment: AecorSoft Integration Service for SAP BW would address this issue, to let you push data from external sources into SAP BW ADSO or DSO objects.